# How do I use commands with spaces with Expl mode on?

Tags: tikz-pgf, expl3

### The Problem

I want to put a command inside an `xparse` section so I can do a fancy little if/else option.  However, the command I am issuing includes a native space inside the options: `TikZ`'s node option called `inner sep` requires a space in the wording.  When I activate the L3, the space seems to be gobbled.

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}

\begin{document}
    \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
        \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=0.5pt] (char) {A};
    }

    \ExplSyntaxOn
    \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
        \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=0.5pt] (char) {B};
    }
    \ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

When executed, I see an error that reads "Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/innersep', [...]" suggesting the space was sent to the void.

### What I want

How can I issue the command inside the L3 block and not have the space in `inner sep` disappear?

### Yes but....

I know that this simple example is achievable with `\ifx` or other simple method.  I am using this as an opportunity to learn more about L3 syntax.

Comment: use `~` to enter a space, so  `inner~sep`.

Comment: Wow.  That is so obvious.  I almost want to delete this question to hide my shame.  Can you put that in an answer so I can select it as a solution.

Comment: also you only need `xparse` if you haved an old latex.